# sorting nested array by integer size

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Googling around I found this function to sort an array by integer size easily, and tested it out in jsfiddle, works as intended (console logs 140000, 104, 99).

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return b - a;
}

var numArray = [104, 99, 140000];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
console.log(numArray);
```

So I tried to implement it in a solution for a [freeCodeCamp exericse](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays?solution=function%20largestOfFour%28arr%29%20%7B%0A%20%20for%28var%20x%3D0%3B%20x%3Carr.lenght%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20arr[x]%20%3D%20arr[x].sort%28function%28a%2Cb%29%20%7B%20return%20b%20-%20a%3B%20%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20arr%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AlargestOfFour%28[[4%2C%205%2C%201%2C%203]%2C%20[13%2C%2027%2C%2018%2C%2026]%2C%20[32%2C%2035%2C%2037%2C%2039]%2C%20[1000%2C%201001%2C%20857%2C%201]]%29%3B%0A), and somehow can't get it to work. The only difference is that now I have a nested array to process. So I want to loop trough all the arrays nested in the arr element (for example largetsOfFour), and sort the integers inside the arrays by size. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for(var x=0; x<arr.lenght; x++) {
    arr[x] = arr[x].sort(function(a,b) { return b - a; });
  }
  return arr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: remplace  arr.lenght by arr.length. And pls, check your logs next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo. It should have been `arr.length`, not `arr.lenght`.

Since there is no such property called `lenght` exists in `arr`, it returns `undefined`.

```
console.log([].lenght);
// undefined
```

and `undefined` can never be compared with numbers. So when compared with `x`'s initial value, zero, it returns `false`.

```
console.log(0 < undefined);
// false
```

It is because, when a number and another object are compared, both of them will be converted to numbers and `undefined` when converted to a number will return `NaN` and `NaN` will be equal to NOTHING (not even to itself).

```
console.log(+undefined);
// NaN
console.log(NaN === NaN);
// false
```

So the loop in `largestOfFour` is never executed and so the sorting functions are. That is why your arrays are not sorted at all.